# Can we decrypt user id from google home request body in dialogflow?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am getting the request JSON from googlehome request:

```
"user": {
    "lastSeen": "2018-12-24T08:42:42Z",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "userId": "ABwppHGejC50Av4qx7dLYCacumFL0Lhte94TCAaJCfTHkr2jMBN8A3re3kMBvCnUezQ3XcBrjp3nxyl8FElOD8KAERdYHA"
},
```

Can we get email address or user id by decrypting this "userId"?

Answer (score 0):

Not the `userId` field, no.

In fact, this field has been deprecated, and [will be removed](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info) in May 2019.

However...

You can setup [account linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in) and request the user connect via Google Sign In for Assistant. This will give you an `idToken` which contains information such as their email address and Google user ID. If you're using the actions-on-google library, it will decode this token (if present) and make the information available in [`conv.user.profile.payload`](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation.profile.html#payload).